# Set appropriate colours for a shape in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to draw a basic square using Qt, my problem is that colours are different than I expect. I wanted blue square on a greed background with red borders. Instead this I get what you can see on the picture. What should be wrong?

[image]

```
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QRect>
#include <QLabel>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPixmap pix(200,100);
    QPainter painter(&pix);

    painter.setBackground(QBrush("#1ac500")); //green
    painter.setPen(QColor("#bd3758")); //red
    painter.setBrush(QBrush("#377dbd"));//blue
    QRect rect(10,10,50,50);

    painter.drawRect(rect);
    painter.end();
    ui->label->setPixmap(pix);
}
```

I also tried following, but with the same effect

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

QPixmap pix(200,100);
QPainter painter(&pix);
painter.setBackground(QBrush("#1ac500")); //green
painter.setPen(Qt::red); //red
QRect rect(10,10,50,50);
painter.fillRect(rect,Qt::red);

painter.drawRect(rect);
painter.end();
ui->label->setPixmap(pix);
}
```

my .ui file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="windowModality">
   <enum>Qt::NonModal</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1920</width>
    <height>1080</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>1820</width>
      <height>980</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignTop</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1920</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionGenerate_Map"/>
    <addaction name="actionLoad_Map"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuEdit">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Edit</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionPreferences"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuHelp">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Help</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionAbout"/>
    <addaction name="actionAuthor"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
   <addaction name="menuEdit"/>
   <addaction name="menuHelp"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionGenerate_Map">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Generate Map</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionPreferences">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Preferences</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionAbout">
   <property name="text">
    <string>About</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionAuthor">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Author</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionLoad_Map">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Load Map</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Didn't know "#abcdef" would work .. Does "green", "red" and "blue" work ?

Comment: no, the effect is the same.

Comment: @Aaron it should work http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#setNamedColor. Also `Qt::red`, `Qt::blue`, `Qt::green` enumeration values works.

Comment: What does pix.depth() tell you ?

Comment: From the docs *Warning: This will create a QPixmap with uninitialized data. Call fill() to fill the pixmap with an appropriate color before drawing onto it with QPainter.*

Comment: @wair92 I couldn't reproduce your problem. My result http://i.imgur.com/moPbRrB.png As you can see rectangle is drawn with correct colors. Problem with the background is because `QPixmap` is not initialized. Maybe your problem is similar, can you try calling `QPixmap::fill()` before drawing?

Comment: I also experienced the jitter shown by HeyYO's example but never a mono-chromic effect. I guess the `setBackground()` should wipe any jitter in his case.

Comment: @HeyYO, it`s pretty interesting, I tried a QPixmap::fill() function, but now only background has changed, and not to green but to white. But for example when I fill a rectangle with a white or a black colour, it is really black or white, I just cannot set it to any different colour like B or W.

Comment: Did you change any settings in your designer form? Is this a clean project with default settings? I want to know if there something we don't see in the post above.

Comment: @HeyYO I did some changes in the ui, but only via QtCreator. I don`t think that I influence something. I can paste here my .ui code if it is needed.

Comment: @Aaron pix.depth() returns me 32

Comment: What QRGB colors do you read back using `pix.toImage().pixel(20,20)` ? The color you set for your painter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your UI file you have `mainWindow.enabled` = `false` (disabled). I believe this changes the color palette of the mainwindow. That's why you get *wrong* colors.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.